# Only part of my storage is showing up in "Other locations" on 22.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, 22.04

I want to preface this by saying I'm extremely new to Ubuntu, so bear with me if my explanation isn't the best.

When I go to the "Other Locations" tab in files, it shows:

Computer                      433.4 GB/470.9GB available /

The issue with this is I have another 1000GB available that I can't seem to get it to recognize.

I *think* I partitioned and mounted the drive to /

I just want the computer to recognize the rest of the storage. How do I do this?

lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0    74M  1 loop /snap/bitwarden/68
loop2    7:2    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop3    7:3    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop4    7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop5    7:5    0 155.6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1232
loop6    7:6    0 162.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1443
loop7    7:7    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop8    7:8    0 254.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/106
loop9    7:9    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop10   7:10   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop11   7:11   0 176.9M  1 loop /snap/krita/64
loop12   7:12   0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop13   7:13   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/575
loop14   7:14   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop15   7:15   0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop16   7:16   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop17   7:17   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3   8:3    0 446.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

Comment: If you run the Disks Utility - that should give you an overview of what Ubuntu can see. Does the missing drive space show in that?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit your question and include the output of the following command `lsblk`. Also, after you paste the output into your question, highlight the block of code and then press CTRL+K to automatically format it. Thanks.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts Yep, it shows there. It says it's not mounted though, and I'm pretty sure it should have been mounted.

Comment: @mchid I've added the output.

Comment: @mchid Looks like you may need to partition it first for Ubuntu to automount the drive. You should be able to do that from the Disks utility.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts I think you are speaking to sam.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts hey, thank you! i got it working and it shows up now. :-)